# C++ random access to a file position

Tags: c++, file-io, random-access

I fell like I'm missing something very simple here, but I can't figure out what.

I have a class `Line` which represents a line in a file and a `GetText` member function which reads that line, as follows:

```
class Line {
    streampos pos_;
    ifstream &file_;
public:
    Line(ifstream &f, streampos pos): pos_(pos), file_(f) { }

    string GetText() const {
        string line;
        // Note the current pos and state
        streampos tpos = file_.tellg();
        iosbase::iostate state = file_.rdstate(); file_.clear();
        file_.seekg(pos_, file_.beg);
        getline(file_, line);
        file_.seekg(tpos, file_.beg); file_.setstate(state);
        return line;
    }
};
```

I have this program which is supposed to print all the lines of the file, by using the class:

```
streampos c = f.tellg();
while (getline(f, line)) {
    Line l(f, c); 
    cout << l.GetText() << endl;
    c = f.tellg();
}
```

Please ignore the face that I could just print out `line`, above. When I run it on the very simple input file

```
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
```

instead of printing out all the lines, the output is:

```
This is line1
his is line2
```

The 't' is missing and the third line's not printed. What's even weirder is that the output of the second line depends on the number of lines! What's the problem with the random jumping? I've been stuck with this for hours.

Comment: That code works well for me. Is this the original code?

Comment: I also tried your code, it works just as expected. `GetText()` preserves the original stream state, the correctness is verifiable.

Comment: @liliscent Ok, weirdest thing ever: after you said that, I copied the exact code to an Ubuntu pc, compiled and ran it, and it works exactly as expected. On a Windows PC, it doesn't(it's not a `\r` issue). Wonder why

Comment: I tested on my Mac OS X, with clang++ compiler. So maybe it's a windows problem. I'm not familiar with windows, but I suspect that getline, because I heard many things about windows newline.

Comment: @forumulator Maybe you can just try GetText multiple times to see whether it always returns the same thing.

Comment: I tested the code on Visual Studio 2017 15.5 on Windows 10 (with C++17 enabled), and it seems to work, though I did correct some errors such as `iosbase` being `ios_base`.